# Having trouble finding what an empty token's value is for a empty csv value

Tags: c, csv

So I want to create a C program that will read through a csv file that may have some empty values. I need my program to still set the tokens equal to an empty value if there is one. I wrote this code since strtok() will simply ignore all empty values.

The program works by taking that record string, and breaking it apart into 3 tokens by these if checks.

```
char record[100] = "1,,3,";

        char delimiter[] = ",";
        char *token1 = 0;
        char *token2 = 0;
        char *token3 = 0;



        static char *stringtobetokened = NULL;
        char *p= 0;
        stringtobetokened = record;

        if ((p = strpbrk(stringtobetokened, delimiter)) != NULL) {
            *p = 0;
            token1 = stringtobetokened;
            stringtobetokened = ++p;
            printf("token1's value:%s\n", token1);

        }

        if ((p = strpbrk(stringtobetokened, delimiter)) != NULL) {
            *p = 0;


            token2 = stringtobetokened;
            stringtobetokened = ++p;
            printf("token2's value:%s\n", token2);
            //this is where the issue is, this if check should be triggered since token2 is a empty value which should print the statement, token2 is null
            if (token2 == NULL)
            {
                printf("token2 is null\n");
                //insert some code that changes token2's value

            }

        }
        if ((p = strpbrk(stringtobetokened, delimiter)) != NULL) {
            *p = 0;
            token3 = stringtobetokened;
            stringtobetokened = ++p;
            printf("token3's value:%s\n", token3);

        }
```

My issue is that while it does pick up that token 2 is empty, the if check

```
if (token2 == NULL)
```

doesn't trigger. I want this if check to trigger so I can insert some code there that change's its value.

if token 2 isn't null or '\0' then what is it's value??

These are the results I get when I run said code:

```
token1's value:1
token2's value:
token3's value:3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Just tried if (token2 == ' ') and that also didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`token2` will be pointing to `empty` string since you are replacing `,` with `0` in previous tokenizing process.

```
                      token1 ----
                                 |
                               +---+---+---+-----
 stringtobetokened      =      | 1 | 0 | 0 |........
                               +---+---+---+-----
                                         |
                               token2 ----
```

Replace your `if` check with below condition.

```
 if (*token2 == '\0')
```

Comment: You're a saint. Thank you!

Comment: @Ely Happy to help.